# Vim set working directory fto first opened directory/file by default

Tags: vim

I kind of new to vim, and when I usually edit things in vim I go something like:

```
vim .
```

or

```
vim /path/to/some/project
```

And then Ctrl-P to the file I need to edit. The problem with this approach is that plugins like NERDTree or FZF understand that the working directory is the one I started vim from not the directory I gave it as the parameter. Example:

```
/some/path$ vim /other/path
```

vim would understand that `/some/path` is the working directory not `/other/path`. Because of this I would have to manually `:cd :%p:%h` each time I start vim. Is there a way to make vim automatically `:cd` to the first opened directory?

Comment: A thought. Set `CDPATH` to you project path. e.g. `export CDPAH=".:~/projects"`. This will let you switch between projects easily with `cd` (and `:cd` inside of Vim)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never thougth about that, but while reading your question i thougth, that could be nice ... or totaly horrible. Anyway interesting problem and I tried it for like 30 seconds and already hate it. The reason is, that your projectfolder almost never directly contains code files which you want to edit.

It should work like this:

```
autocmd VimEnter * silent! cd %:p:h
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). I use Ctrl+P from there to get to where I want. I find it faster than typing shell the entire path to the file. Just as a side note, is there a way for vim to detect whether if the parameter is a file, you do not want the command above triggered but when it's a directory you do?

Comment: sure you want. because `:echo expand("%:p:h")` on `vim /folder/file` gives the same result as on `vim /folder` the `:h` flag does not remove a folder from a path. So i would always open a folder with that, since i would go to my project folder and use Ctrl+P or fzf or whatever from there. But if I have to type the path anyway I can use `cd` which I prefer, because i will stay in the project folder after closing vim (not that I ever close vim). And it does not mess with my directory if i want to open a specific file in my subfolders.